# Different principals in spring security context when 'in-bean' login method used

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3, spring-social

For couple of days I have been working on integrating Facebook with our application. I have successfully made the connection working and now after Facebook Login I copy the user to our database and later on I want to **use our internal principal within context**.

---

For the Spring security login we overloaded our **authentication-manager** with our class implemeting `UserDetailsService`.

When someone logs in with facebook, he has abstract credentials he can not know.
I used this method in my Facebook login controller to log him in:

```
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
    profile.getId(), new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(
    profile.getEmail() + profile.getId(), null),
    (Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>) getAuthorities(profile.getId()));
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

Within some controllers I use

`public String profile(Locale locale, Model model, HttpSession session, Principal principal)`and then `principal` **actually contains different Objects.**

*For regular spring security login its:*

`org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4527d081: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A5E9AB9E4AEE7486EC4B4F6133F77320; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN`

*But after login with the method in the controller its:*
`org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@cd4699c5: Principal: 1405308431; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT`

---

**QUESTION:**
I really don't want to distinguish between these types in all my controllers. Why it differs?! It obviously is a User (my type) object when we login with normal credentials and its just a String for facebook. **How can I change it so facebook login would give me User object in my security context too?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up SignInAdapter as described at the end of [this chapiter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/signin.html#d4e851). In the `SignInAdapter.signIn(...)` method you can load your user object from DB then prepare authentication object and inject it in security context holder.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really get the 'prepare authentication object' at first but it was really easy;
I post this example for future clarification *maybe one will need it* :)

```
public class FacebookAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken 
{   
private final org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails principal;
private String credentials;

public FacebookAuthenticationToken(org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails details,FacebookProfile profile, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities){
    super(authorities);
    this.principal = details;
    this.credentials = new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(profile.getEmail()+profile.getId(), null);
    super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7545290433068513777L;

public Object getCredentials() {
    return this.credentials;
}

public Object getPrincipal() {
    return this.principal;
}

}
```

---

And now i understood I could have even used the [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html),
just provide the `Object principal` with correct class. Silly me.